# Is it acceptable to pass a base64 string from the client to the server to utilize?

Tags: c#, image

Is it acceptable to pass a base64 string from the client to the server to save?

Client save I have code that creates a BASE64 string...
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh.....etc....

However when I try to convert this server side I get an error that input is not a valid Base-64 string.

In my C# code I have:

```
// Data Type
public List<object[][]> MyData;


var imgStr = MyData[0][0].ToString();
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imgStr); // Get error here
```

Is there a better way to take an image from client slide and pass it server side to use?

Comment: Have you verified that `imgStr` contains the exact Base64 string that was created on the client?

Comment: Does the string you want to convert contain the `data:` URI? It should just use the stuff after `base64,`...

Comment: As a note base64 takes 33% more bandwidth than it's binary counter part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples) is made up of characters `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, `+`, and `/`, putting aside the number of `=` characters that must be placed at the end (the most complicated part about Base64 *encoding),

As you can see in your data string, the `data:image/png;base64,` prefix is simply [metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata) and is not part of any valid Base64 encoded string. Here is a way you could remove this from your string:

```
String base64 = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh.....";
base64 = base64.substring(22, base64.length());
```

If you want it to work for any image type, you will need to use a regular expression.

Comment: Base64 is not encryption, it is an encoding.

Answer (score 4):

You need to strip the `data:image/png;base64,` from the string. That's metadata. The actual base64 encoded bytes begins after the comma.

Answer (score 1):

Following @benstopics response, it might be easier to strip the metadata by splitting on the comma and then taking the second part e.g.

```
String base64 = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh.....";
base64 = base64.split(',')[1];
```